# method to parse composite csv is behaving weirdly

Tags: java, parsing, csv

this question is related to a previous question i posted at:

[parsing split csv files in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025618/parsing-split-csv-files-in-java/23025888)

it is related to a method i am trying to write that is able to split a csv file into several different arraylists, where the data for each list is separated by a comment denoted by "%"

here is the code that i have written:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<int[]>> parseValues(Scanner input, int size)
{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<int[]>> output = new ArrayList<ArrayList<int[]>>();
    boolean state = false;
    boolean lastState = false;
    int count = 0;
    int i = -1;

    System.out.println();

    while (input.hasNextLine())
    {
        String temp = input.nextLine();

        if (temp.startsWith("%"))
            state = false;
        else
            state = true;

        if (state != lastState)
        {
            count++;
        }

        if (count % 2 == 0)
        {
            output.add(new ArrayList<int[]>());
            System.out.println("====new list====");
            i++;
        }

        lastState = state;

        if (!temp.startsWith("%"))
        {
            int j = 0;
            int[] values = new int[size];

            for (String value: temp.split(","))
            {
                try
                {
                    values[j] = Integer.parseInt(value);
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    values[j] = 0;
                }

                j++;
            }

            output.get(i).add(values);
        }
        System.out.println("count = " + count + "  count%2 = " + 
                (count%2) + "  state = " + state + "  lastState = " + 
                lastState +"  output.size() = " + output.size() + 
                "  output[i].size() = " + output.get(i).size());
    }

    return output;
}
```

(the println statements are all just for debugging)

when i feed the following file into the algorithm:

```
% into ArrayList<Integer> list1
3,4,5,2,2,3
5,6,3,2,4,5
3,2,3,4,5,6
2,3,4,5,1,3
4,3,5,4,3,2
4,4,3,4,5,4
% 
% the values below here should go
% into ArrayList<Integer> list2
4,6,3,4,5,3
3,4,5,6,3,2
4,5,6,4,3,2
3,4,3,2,4,5
4,5,3,2,5,3
4,3,4,5,3,2
4,4,3,2,4,5
7,5,4,5,6,7
6,4,3,5,6,4
```

i get the following output:

```
====new list====
count = 0  count%2 = 0  state = false  lastState = false  output.size() = 1  output[i].size() = 0
count = 1  count%2 = 1  state = true  lastState = true  output.size() = 1  output[i].size() = 1
count = 1  count%2 = 1  state = true  lastState = true  output.size() = 1  output[i].size() = 2
count = 1  count%2 = 1  state = true  lastState = true  output.size() = 1  output[i].size() = 3
count = 1  count%2 = 1  state = true  lastState = true  output.size() = 1  output[i].size() = 4
count = 1  count%2 = 1  state = true  lastState = true  output.size() = 1  output[i].size() = 5
count = 1  count%2 = 1  state = true  lastState = true  output.size() = 1  output[i].size() = 6
====new list====
count = 2  count%2 = 0  state = false  lastState = false  output.size() = 2  output[i].size() = 0
====new list====
count = 2  count%2 = 0  state = false  lastState = false  output.size() = 3  output[i].size() = 0
====new list====
count = 2  count%2 = 0  state = false  lastState = false  output.size() = 4  output[i].size() = 0
count = 3  count%2 = 1  state = true  lastState = true  output.size() = 4  output[i].size() = 1
count = 3  count%2 = 1  state = true  lastState = true  output.size() = 4  output[i].size() = 2
count = 3  count%2 = 1  state = true  lastState = true  output.size() = 4  output[i].size() = 3
count = 3  count%2 = 1  state = true  lastState = true  output.size() = 4  output[i].size() = 4
count = 3  count%2 = 1  state = true  lastState = true  output.size() = 4  output[i].size() = 5
count = 3  count%2 = 1  state = true  lastState = true  output.size() = 4  output[i].size() = 6
count = 3  count%2 = 1  state = true  lastState = true  output.size() = 4  output[i].size() = 7
count = 3  count%2 = 1  state = true  lastState = true  output.size() = 4  output[i].size() = 8
count = 3  count%2 = 1  state = true  lastState = true  output.size() = 4  output[i].size() = 9
```

which is ALMOST what i want, except it is creating extra lists for every state change instead of every 2nd state change, which is what i want..

ive been mucking around with it for ages now and i cant quite seem to get it to do what i want it to do.. im sure it is something very simple but i cant for hte life of me work it out.. does anyone else have an idea why it is doing that? any help would be greatly appreciated.. thanks!

Comment: Your variable names are quite confusing. What do `state` and `lastState` stand for? Also, you haven't mentioned what you want the `output` list to have when the processing is complete.

Comment: You said - "... where the data for each list is separated by a comment denoted by "%"" but your sample data doesn't support that.

Comment: @bhesh - state stands for whether it is currently a line with "%" or not (false for %, true for whatever else) and lastState stands for the state of the previous line, so if there is a change (either from % to not, or vice versa) between the lines, it increments the counter. then the counter % 2 is supposed to be activated every 2nd state change (from data, to % and back to data)

Comment: also, how does my sample data not support that? it has a comment at the top, followed by lines of data for arraylist1, then another 3 lines of comments, followed by lines of data for arraylist 2. the output of the method is an ArrayList of ArrayLists of int[], so in the case of this sample data, it should have an arraylist, consisting of two arraylists, one 6 elements long, and the second 9 elements long. with each element being an array of int that is itself 6 elements long

Comment: i will probably change it from using int arrays to something more OOP-ish, but my question is more about the algorithm for creating the arraylists than how i am storing the data. sorry if i was unclear about anything in my original question, i hope it is clearer now

Comment: So if a line starting with a `%` is immediately followed by another line starting with a `%`, then you really don't want a list for that. I was thinking you wanted a empty list in that case.

Comment: no i just want nothing at all for those lines.. this is my problem..

Comment: i worked it out! my problem was that it was toggling with every change at modulo 2, so i just needed to make it modulo 4 and increment count every time it creates a new list so it doesnt sit on x % 4 = 0 for ever, creating new lists with each piece of data.. ergh, that was annoying!

Answer (score 0):

after much experimenting and hair pulling i managed to find the answer.. if anyone is interested or gets stuck with a similar problem, this bit of code here:

```
if (count % 2 == 0)
    {
        output.add(new ArrayList<int[]>());
        System.out.println("====new list====");
        i++;
    }
```

needed to be changed to:

```
if (count % 4 == 0)
    {
        output.add(new ArrayList<int[]>());
        System.out.println("====new list====");
        count++;
        i++;
    }
```

the modulo 4 ensuring that it toggled every 2 state change instead of every state change, and the count++ ensuring that count % 4 != 0 on the next pass and so create yet another list..

phew! that was annoying, but glad to have it solved!